# UIViewController - Can't change image within vcontroller.view via IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, iboutlet

Ok, I used a work-around for something similar to this last night...but a workaround won't suffice for my new situation, so I figured I should find out what I'm missing.

I have a UIViewController that has a main UIView item, and 2 UIButton objects and a UIImageView.  I have the File's Owner set to my view controller class.  The ViewController has a class variable "IBOutlet UIImageView * backgroundImage".  I have set the outlet in Interface Builder such that the UIImageView references the "backgroundImage" property.

I would assume at this point that I should be able to change the UIImageView item.  However, this is not the case.  I can set it in code, and my app does NOT blow up (due to a lack of outlet setting or anything), but the image simply doesn't change.  I was trying something VERY similar to this last night where I had a UIView within the root UIView item of the ViewController and I was trying to reference that to a class variable to specifically control that view.  However, that never worked either.

How can I control (via IB and outlets) the subview items of a UIViewController.view?

Just to be explicit, here is my setup:

UINavigationController
--> UITableViewController (tvc)

From the "tvc", push a new UIViewController (vc, notice this isn't a table).  *<-- This is what I'm describing above*

In the "vc" (UIViewController):

- File's Owner = MyDetailsViewController (subclassed from UIViewController)
- UIView

  - UIImageView **<-- This is what I'm trying to control specifically, as mentioned above**
  - Button
  - Button

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the actual image for the UIImageView like

```
backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];  
//(Where myImage.png has been added to to your project)
```

Comment: Yes I am setting it as you specify here.

Comment: Can you add some code, my only thought is that the outlet must not be connected in IB. If it wasn't set, it will not "blow up".  It will just change the image of a UIImageView that you cannot see.